# Calling QUnit's assert.async function multiple times

Tags: javascript, qunit

I'm using QUnit to test a javascript library, and I need to verify that a callback is invoked more than one time. According to the QUnit docs (at http://api.qunitjs.com/async/), something like this simplified test case should work:

```
QUnit.test("assert.async with argument", function (assert) {

var done = assert.async(3);

done();
done();
done();
});
```

However, the above throws exception, `Called the callback returned from assert.async more than once`.

I have to resort to building an array of done() functions, and then popping each off and invoking it. Not as nice.

### Update

On upgrading QUnit to 2.0.1, the code above will work (modulo a complaint that 0 assertions were made). I had been using version 1.18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

The OP commented below, he just needed to upgrade QUnit!

...

I have a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmoyf7hp/1/) where you can see this working asynchronously (with `setTimeout`) and one without (your example).

Here is an example which does work (with QUnit 2.0.1 anyway) using `setTimeout`:

```
QUnit.test( "multiple call done()", function( assert ) {
  var done = assert.async( 2 );

  setTimeout(function() {
    assert.ok( true, "first call done." );
    done();
  }, 500 );

  setTimeout(function() {
    assert.ok( true, "second call done." );
    done();
  }, 500 );
});
```

Comment: This isn't quite true -- this code runs fine in 2.0.1, but it also works without wrapping the done() calls in setTimeout(). I solved my problem by upgrading.

Comment: Ha! You are correct. My test failed because I had no assertions... I'll update the answer, but glad you got it solved!